# Modifying SQL code to pick the Dropdown list instead of constant text

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

In the below query I would like to redirect ''MyDivision_1'' (MyDivision_1 is a constant text) to a dropdown list selection.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbFOConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="/* COLUMNS HEADERS */
                    DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR (MAX)

                    SELECT @columnHeaders  = COALESCE (@columnHeaders   
                    + ',[' + sStockistName + ']', '[' + sStockistName + ']')


                    FROM   TblPresentStock  
                    GROUP BY sStockistName
                    ORDER BY sStockistName


                    /* GRAND TOTAL COLUMN */
                    DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
                    SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
                    CAST (sStockistName AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
                    FROM     TblPresentStock 
                      GROUP BY sStockistName
                      ORDER BY sStockistName
                     SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

                    /* GRAND TOTAL ROW */
                    DECLARE @GrandTotalRow  NVARCHAR(MAX)
                    SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
                    CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
                    FROM     TblPresentStock  
                        GROUP BY sStockistName
                      ORDER BY  sStockistName
                    ----------------------------------------------

                     -- DROP TABLE  temp_MatchesTotal

                    /* MAIN QUERY */
                    DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)
                    SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') 
                    AS [Grand Total] INTO  #temp_MatchesTotal
                                FROM
                                    (SELECT sProductName,sDivision,sStockistName,Qty
                                        FROM  TblPresentStock where sDivision = ''MyDivision_1''
                                    )A
                                PIVOT
                                    (
                                     sum (Qty)
                                     FOR sStockistName
                                     IN ('  +@columnHeaders +  ') 
                                    ) B 

                    ORDER BY sProductName,sDivision
                    SELECT * FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT ''Grand Total'','''','+@GrandTotalRow +',  
                    ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal
                      DROP TABLE  #temp_MatchesTotal'
                     -- PRINT 'Pivot Query '+@FinalQuery
                     -- SELECT @FinalQuery
                     EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The above SQL query is in an aspx page (design mode).

Any suggestion will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a parameter inside `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT sProductName, sDivision, sStockistName, Qty FROM TblPresentStock 
WHERE sDivision = @MyDivision_1
```

Then use parameter name with `ControlParameter` inside `SelectParameters` option in `SqlDataSource`, by setting `PropertyName="SelectedValue"` from dropdown list:

```
<%-- Dropdownlist example --%>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ... />
    <asp:ListItem Text="SampleText" Value="SampleValue" />
    ...
</asp:DropDownList>

<%-- SqlDataSource --%>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbFOConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="..." ...>
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1"
              PropertyName="SelectedValue"
              Name="MyDivision_1"
              Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Note:** The passed type in `ControlParameter` must match with type defined in `SelectedValue` attribute of dropdown list.

Related issue:

[How to assign DropDownList selected value to SqlDataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683942/how-to-assign-dropdownlist-selected-value-to-sqldatasource)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just copy and paste the `SelectCommand` value to any SQL editor with desired parameter value and run it afterwards.

Comment: Your answer helped me to achieve my goal but its not working when I use it with actual query.  You can see the elaboration in the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773944/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-mydivision-1?noredirect=1#comment94399355_53773944

Comment: Will be very helpful If you have a look in the above given link and please share your valuable suggestions.