# Must declare the scalar variable "@MyDivision_1"

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

This works fine:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbFOConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT sProductName,sDivision,sStockistName,Qty
                    FROM TblPresentStock 
                    WHERE sDivision = @MyDivision_1 " >
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision"
              PropertyName="SelectedValue"
              Name="MyDivision_1"
              Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This also works fine:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbFOConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="/* COLUMNS HEADERS */
                DECLARE @columnHeaders NVARCHAR (MAX)

                SELECT @columnHeaders  = COALESCE (@columnHeaders   
                       + ',[' + sStockistName + ']', '[' + sStockistName + ']')
                FROM   TblPresentStock  
                GROUP BY sStockistName
                ORDER BY sStockistName

                /* GRAND TOTAL COLUMN */
                DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
                SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + 
                       CAST (sStockistName AS VARCHAR) +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+ '],0) + ')
                FROM TblPresentStock 
                GROUP BY sStockistName
                ORDER BY sStockistName

                SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

                /* GRAND TOTAL ROW */
                DECLARE @GrandTotalRow  NVARCHAR(MAX)
                SELECT @GrandTotalRow = COALESCE(@GrandTotalRow + ',ISNULL(SUM([' + 
                CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)', 'ISNULL(SUM([' + CAST(sStockistName AS VARCHAR)+']),0)')
                FROM     TblPresentStock  
                    GROUP BY sStockistName
                  ORDER BY  sStockistName
                ----------------------------------------------

                 -- DROP TABLE  temp_MatchesTotal

                /* MAIN QUERY */
                DECLARE @FinalQuery NVARCHAR (MAX)
                SET @FinalQuery =   'SELECT *, (' + @GrandTotalCol + ') 
                AS [Grand Total] INTO  #temp_MatchesTotal
                            FROM
                                (SELECT sProductName,sDivision,sStockistName,Qty
                                    FROM  TblPresentStock 
                                )A
                            PIVOT
                                (
                                 sum (Qty)
                                 FOR sStockistName
                                 IN ('  +@columnHeaders +  ') 
                                ) B 

                ORDER BY sProductName,sDivision
                SELECT * FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ''Grand Total'','''','+@GrandTotalRow +',  
                ISNULL (SUM([Grand Total]),0) FROM  #temp_MatchesTotal
                  DROP TABLE  #temp_MatchesTotal'
                 -- PRINT 'Pivot Query '+@FinalQuery
                 -- SELECT @FinalQuery
                 EXECUTE(@FinalQuery)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision"
             PropertyName="SelectedValue"
             Name="MyDivision_1"
             Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In the above query when I replace this line:

```
SELECT ProductName, sDivision, sStockistName, Qty
FROM TblPresentStock
```

with this:

```
SELECT sProductName, sDivision, sStockistName, Qty 
FROM TblPresentStock 
WHERE sDivision = @MyDivision_1
```

An error occurs:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@MyDivision_1"

The only addition is

```
WHERE sDivision = @MyDivision_1
```

If I mention the division name specifically like the below then it's working fine and getting the data of that particular division without any error.

```
WHERE sDivision = ''Div1''
```

Comment: Has a value been selected for the DropDownList `ddlDivision` at the point where the query runs?

Comment: Yes, but If I am not wrong eventhough there is no value in the dropdown then the query should result blank right.  The First query is working fine which targets the same dropdown.

Comment: I've certainly had issues with the default values of parameters before.

Comment: Hm... But the first query is working fine which also targets the same dropdown list.

Comment: To debug add the event handler `OnSelecting` and inspect the command that has been created. You'll be able to see a) Whether the parameter exists, and b) whether its been assigned a meaningful value. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Try checking for `IsPostBack` in your `Page_Load` event handler if you reloading records from somewhere. Since you're using `ControlParameter`, make sure that the parameter is filled when the grid is (re)loaded. I recommend you to use stored procedure instead of using long query string inside `SelectCommand`.

Comment: Yes Postback is on.  The first query is working fine but when I add "WHERE sDivision = @MyDivision_1" in the second query it fails and throws error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must declare scalar variable @Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771791/must-declare-scalar-variable-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needs to replace this

```
WHERE sDivision = @MyDivision_1
```

With

```
WHERE sDivision = ''' + @MyDivision_1 + '''
```

> ***[This](http://sqlhints.com/2015/06/28/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-error-message-137/) article helped me to fix the issue.***